# Xamarin iOS restore PlaceHolder

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a Xamarin iOS application and some textfields, each one has a placeholder and it is deleted when it is selected, I want it to be restored when the input is null or empty, how do I get it?

```
I tried that:

    public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
    {
       base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
       string placeholderAux = txt.Placeholder;
       txt.EditingDidBegin += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>{
           if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt.Text))
           {
              txt.Placeholder = placeholderAux;
           }
       };
}
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: You want to restore the placeholder if the text field is **empty and not selected**? Or?

Comment: i want to restore the same placeholder when i click out of the texfield and this is empty

Comment: It sounds like you are removing the Placeholder text at some point when all you have to do is set it once `txt.Placeholder = "Your Placeholder";` and all of that will be handled for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Clear the placeholder when starting to edit.

```
textField.EditingDidBegin += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
{
    (sender as UITextField).Placeholder = "";
};
```

#### Reset the placeholder when first responser is changed and the field is empty:

```
textField.EditingDidEnd += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
{
    var uITextField = sender as UITextField;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(uITextField.Text))
    {
        uITextField.Placeholder = "StackOverflow";
    }
};
```